# Why is my loop not waiting between iterations? setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm building a Simon says game http://codepen.io/meek/pen/adrbOv using jquery and I'm having some trouble with playing back each sound one by one.

When the game starts, a list of 20 sounds ("moves") is generated, which will play one by one each turn. So if the moves list is [ 'red', 'yellow', 'green'], on turn one 'red' will play, on turn two 'red' and 'yellow' will play, and so on.

I've set the turn to 4 and I'm trying to get each sound to play one after the other, until 4 sounds are played. I'm using this code:

```
turn = 4;
var t = 1;
  while(t <= turn) {
    setTimeout(AIbutton(allMoves[t-1]), 1000);
    t++;
  }
```

`AIbutton()` is the function that plays a sound (simulates a button press) and `allMoves` is the list of 20 moves that will play throughout the game. What I want for it to happen is that a sound is played on each iteration of the loop before moving onto the next iteration, but what happens is that all the sounds in the loop iterates over play at the same time after an interval of 1000 ms.

I thought the setTimeout would make it so it pauses between iterations? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

setTimeout runs asynchronously, it is not blocking.  If you want to wait for the timeout to finish, the next "loop iteration" needs to happen in the function callback you are giving setTimeout.

Something like this would work:

```
turn = 4;
var t = 1;
ourTimeout(allMovies, turn, t);

function ourTimeout(allMovies, turn, t){
    AIbutton(allMoves[t-1]);
    if(t <= turn)
        setTimeout(ourTimeout(allMovies, turn, ++t), 1000);
}
```

@Alnitak mentions that this line of code:

```
setTimeout(ourTimeout(allMovies, turn, ++t), 1000);`
```

needs to be changed to this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
        ourTimeout(allMovies, turn, ++t);
    }, 1000);
```

As @Alnitak states, you can only pass an anonoymous or named function to setTimeout.  The trick of passing variables is done as the change above mentions (concept is called a closure).

Comment: this code is incorrect - you need to pass a function reference to `setTimeout` (e.g. an anonymous function expression), not the result of the call to `ourTimeout`.

Comment: That does exactly what I need and I understand why now. Thanks!